# 3D Models not loading on Mapbox using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

My problem is I can't load any .gltf file, only a standard one. Please read further to understand in detail. I have the following map on my application, that has that 3D model pointed by the red arrow:

[image: map]

The model is a GLFT file from [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf).
The code I have is provided by Mapbox itself on their documents, [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/).

Here it is how I have it:

```js
var modelOrigin = [-8.629134, 41.157902];
    var modelAltitude = 0;
    var modelRotate = [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0];
    
    var modelAsMercatorCoordinate = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(modelOrigin,modelAltitude);

    var modelTransform = {translateX: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.x,translateY: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.y,translateZ: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.z,rotateX: modelRotate[0],rotateY: modelRotate[1],rotateZ: modelRotate[2],scale: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits()};

    var THREE = window.THREE;
    var customLayer = {
      id: '3d-model',
      type: 'custom',
      renderingMode: '3d',
      onAdd: function (map, gl) {
      this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
       
      // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
      var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
      directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
      this.scene.add(directionalLight);
       
      var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
      directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
      this.scene.add(directionalLight2);
       
      // use the three.js GLTF loader to add the 3D model to the three.js scene
      var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
      loader.load('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf',function (gltf) {
        this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
      }.bind(this));
      this.map = map;
       
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: map.getCanvas(),
        context: gl,
        antialias: true
      });
       
      this.renderer.autoClear = false;
      },
      render: function (gl, matrix) {
      var rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
      modelTransform.rotateX
      );
      var rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
      modelTransform.rotateY
      );
      var rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
      modelTransform.rotateZ
      );
       
      var m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
      var l = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
        modelTransform.translateX,
        modelTransform.translateY,
        modelTransform.translateZ).scale(
          new THREE.Vector3(
          modelTransform.scale,
          -modelTransform.scale,
          modelTransform.scale)).multiply(rotationX).multiply(rotationY).multiply(rotationZ);
       
      this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
      this.renderer.state.reset();
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      this.map.triggerRepaint();
      }
    };
map.on('load', async () => {
      map.addLayer(customLayer, 'waterway-label');
});
```

As you can see, I have the model link on the `loader.load()` function. It works perfectly for THAT model. Yet, when I try other models, locally and instead of the link, I have something like `('./models/file.gltf)` it doesn't work. I can't understand why, and can't seem to make it work.

Comment: What’s the error you’re getting in the console? 404? Is your gltf model using any kind of compression? Has your gltf model an associated .bin file or textures?

Comment: I'm not getting ANY error. I can use the 3D model from that link, works perfectly, when I change to any other link, or local path like ``` ./models/building.gltf```, it just doesn't show up on the map. Everything works, but the model doesn't show on the map.

Comment: If you are using .gltf models, normally they have an associated .bin file referenced in the code of the .gltf file. Indeed the model from Mapbox has a .bin file in the same folder, you can check it out. Those .bin file must be normally in the same folder as the .gltf

Comment: When I click the link, it instantly downloads the gltf, but I didn't see a .bin file. Even so, when I tried to download a building model, it came with a .bin file along with the .gltf. I placed the .bin and .gltf on the folder and called it like "./model/building.gltf", and it still didn't show up. Where is the .bin you say on the mapbox 3D model?

Comment: I could suggest you to use [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) an specific 3D plug-in for Mapbox where you’ll find dozens of examples with different models and a lot of extended functionality

Comment: One more question, is the scale of the model properly set?? Probably your model is too small or too big to be shown in your zoom level

Comment: var modelTransform = {
      translateX: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.x,
      translateY: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.y,
      translateZ: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.z,
      rotateX: modelRotate[0],
      rotateY: modelRotate[1],
      rotateZ: modelRotate[2],
      scale: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits()};

Comment: I have that, that is supposed to scale it down

Comment: I'm not very experienced, or not at all actually, so I don't know if that is correct, or if what you said is the actual problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226756/discussion-between-jscastro-and-tiagoribeiro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what was the issue in your code, probably it was related to the relative path to the files.

I have created a [PR for you in your repo](https://github.com/TRibeiro94/TEMP/pulls), with a basic node project with 2 examples. The first example is how to load your 3D model using the standard code from Mapbox. The second example is to do the same using [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) and adding some cool features like selecting, rotating, dragging, bounding box and adding tooltips.

[image]

Comment: Hi again, buddy I don't know what might be wrong, not only I can't see the 3D models in your provided html files in my repo, but I can't load them on my project using the same diorama. I noticed you have a .sln, being a visual studio project, and Im using visual code, can that be it? I'm a newbie so I can't quite pin the issue.. This might be farfetched but is there any way we can make some sort of discord/microsoft teams call so I can share the screen? Might be easier and faster (this is due today at 23:59, that's why I ask )

Comment: Now I've tried the treebox way and I'm getting **ReferenceError: tb is not defined** even tho I import Threebox from the scripts folder and all, I'm just doing desperate tries of trial n error atm

Comment: Let's go step by step, the node project should work on its own. You should be able to open the .njsproj in VS code without any issue and just run it, or in the worst case, you can even create a node project yourself in VS code from scratch and just add the files I dropped in your repo

Comment: When I try to use the custom layer function on my project, I use **import Threebox from "../../scripts/threebox.min.js";** because I copied that file, aswell as the .css. I feel that the threebox method would work, but I'm getting **ReferenceError: tb is not defined** when I do the window.tb (...)

Comment: Ok this should be more clear: https://codepen.io/TiagoRibeiro94/pen/VwKXyee?editors=0010 , you you check there I have the component with the Threebox createCustomLayer method at line 56. I'm getting that error on that window.tb . What can that be about? I think after solving that, should be working

Comment: Then you can instantiate threebox outside the `createCustomLayer` like this: 
```
// instantiate threebox
    window.tb = new Threebox(map, 
                             map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'),
                             { defaultLights: true, enableSelectingObjects: true, enableDraggingObjects: true, enableRotatingObjects: true, enableTooltips: true }
                            );
```

Comment: Check if your issue is not related to this as you’re trying to load objects by relative url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526248/webpack-in-react-cant-load-the-3d-model-with-a-gltf-extension-shows-404-not-fo?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C70.3559

Answer (score 1):

On my GLTF loader, when I use that link from the mapbox docs, it loads the object, perfectly:

```js
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf',function (gltf) {
          this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
        }.bind(this));
        this.map = map;
```

Yet, it doesn't work when I trade that link for the original repo link like this:

```
https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/master/examples/models/radar/34M_17.gltf
```

It doesn't crash the app, it simply doesn't load and I get this error:
[image: error]

It's the same when I download all the files into a folder and I use the path like **./folder/34M_17.gltf** , it also doesn't load and shows the same error. And that's what's weird, working one way, and not the other...

Comment: Tiago, there are some misunderstandings on this. You're trying to download from your local app, a resource which is in a github repo not a website, but even if so, you would get a CORS error because a website needs to be CORS-enabled. The reason the resource from Mapbox url works is because first is a website, second is CORS enabled. If you have the code of the app you're trying to build in a repo it'll be easier to help you. Just download all the resources in the radar folder that I provided you, and copy them in your local folder for models. Then change the url and check the console>network